# How to compare image elements with flutter

Tags: flutter, image-comparison

I’m making a geometry-related app to help study by giving an exercise and after the user takes a picture of what they did and it the photo sent with the solution through the lines and seeing if they match, how could that be done?? I’m using flutter to make the app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter's `image_picker` package to let users capture a photo from their camera or select an image from their gallery. Integrate [`OpenCV`](https://pub.dev/packages?q=opencv) into Flutter.